# ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, workflow-foundation

When I try to build My WF project I get this error. I've found that removing `System.Activities.Presentation` solves this error.
If I get this error at runtime, I can investigate `LoaderExceptions` to find out about the root problem.

How can do the same when I get this error at compile time?
Alternatively, does anybody know how to solve this particular problem?

> Extension 'Microsoft.Activities.Build.Validation.ValidationBuildExtension' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' :  'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MsBuild project build output verbosity -> Detailed (or diagnostic)

Visual studio will include much more detailed information about the build process in the output window.

Comment: thanks.I did that and i found that C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets(347,5) gets error. my project is framework 4.5 but gets error in framework 4.

Comment: I had similar problem. When you try to open the workflow on visual studio it will also fail, click on details and see. In my case it was a missing dependency dll, i copied the dll to location it is expected and then everything worked

Comment: Facing similar issue at compile time, in output details there is not much information related specific load exception - below is the error which i got -  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets(347,5): error XC1043: Extension 'Microsoft.Activities.Build.Validation.ValidationBuildExtension' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' :  'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.'. , any information will be good to know

Comment: @IshTech If you change the settings as suggested in the answer, you'll get more information (actually you'll get much much more). Your root cause should be included there. Like what happened to Mehrnoosh

Comment: @Alireza Thanks for the update, There were issues with the nugget reference in my case, I used fusion logger (Fuslogvw.exe) to get the binding issues, that helped