# ReflectionTypeLoadException on InstallUtil

Tags: c#, dll

I'm trying to install a service for my VS 2013 project, and it's refusing to register it with the ReflectionTypeLoadException. I have a .dll attached to my project, but I don't know how it's not working.

Here's the full quote:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

**My Process:**

1. Open up VS2013 Dev CMD prompt
2. cd to my debug folder
3. Type "InstallUtil ProjectName.exe"

**What I have tried:**
I did google around, and here's what I've done:

1. I have inserted my .dll in the same folder as my .exe (the debug). Copy Local is set to "True"
2. I rebuilt the project
3. I have tried copying/running the InstallUtil .exe into the same folder from the .net/Framework, no luck
4. There might have been a second .dll that this one dll is dependent on, but that is in the same debug folder as well and is not referenced in the project.

I have also tried this: http://www.devopsonwindows.com/create-a-windows-service/
But when I write "sc create ServiceName "fullservicepath.exe" " I just get the description of "sc create" and arguments.

What steps am I missing here? Is there any way I can dig into the project and find out what is causing this?

Comment: under your Start button navigate to Visual -Studio, under there go to the Visual Studio Tools folder, then click on the Developer Command Prompt and try it from their..

Comment: That is where I am trying it from.

Comment: can you check out this link for additional things to try.. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526152/reflectiontypeloadexception also in your project are you properly referencing the .dll can you make sure that the `CopyToLocal` property is set = `true` sounds like a reference issue

Comment: The simplest explanation is that you forgot to write an [installer for your service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'll check those two links right now to see, but to mention yes it is set to Copy Local.

Comment: @MethodMan I have tried that link, but no more details come about in the installlog file. I also build just fine.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried that, but whenever I click on any of the design, or lose focus of it in the [Design] and right click, there is no "Add Installer" option in my context menu. I saw that earlier, and tried selecting the whole winform, not selecting, clicking the outside, etc. No luck. It has "View Code, Lock Controls, Select 'WinformName' and Properties"

Comment: they have some really good `YouTube` videos that can walk you step by step in regards to adding / creating an Installer.. I used one last week do do one for a service that I created and had `Zero` issues..

Comment: My crystal ball say that you wrote a Winforms application, not a service.  You do not use InstallUtil.exe on a Winforms app.  Use the proper project template to get started, it is named "Windows Service".

Comment: Hah, if only it were that easy. No I'm using a template form from a third party vendor to go into their software. It hasn't been a smooth ride.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding what you tried with the "sc create" command, you need to put "binPath= " before the path to your executable (there's a space between the = and your file path), like:

```
sc create ServiceName binPath= "fullservicepath.exe"
```

I'm not sure if that will get past your original problem with the TypeLoadException, though.

Comment: The suggested approach worked in my case, which was a Windows docker container scenario. Trying to install a service using InstallUtil.exe threw the "System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information." error, but SC Create worked well - thanks for sharing!